# Email Login on Shared Windows 10 Computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

Is it possible to have a Windows 10 computer available to anyone with an email account to log into (registered with account.microsoft.com, of course)?

I can add users from the administrator account, but I would like to have them added ad-hoc as people need to access the computer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, "Any Microsoft Account" is not a mode that Windows 10 can use to authenticate new users.

In general, you have three options for shared PCs based on your needs:

1. [Manually add their microsoft accounts:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026923)
   Select the Start  button, select Settings  > Accounts  and then select Family & other users. (In some editions of Windows you'll see Other users.) 
   Select Add someone else to this PC, and fill in their email address. This is best for family or other small environments.

[image: microsoft account]

2. If the PC is out in public and only used temporarily for email/web browsing/printing, use **Kiosk Mode** to force only one app, and only one restricted user account that doesn't save user data. See more info about this [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-kiosk-mode-windows-10-october-2018-update)
3. [Advanced] If multiple PCs are going to be used in a work or school environment where they may shuffle around occasionally, consider setting up a windows domain. Any domain user is able to log into any domain PC.

Comment: I think you're right and this is in line with what I have been discovering, too.Basically there are a half dozen machines that we are pulling off of our AD but still used by a random number of people; however, Azure has what seems like a service that could help with this... ultimately it's too much for what I am requiring. In the end, going with a standard login for a user account across all machines will work - Much work is done in the cloud, so this is fine as long as folks remember to log out.
I will award your rep once the timer runs down. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, if you have Azure or Office 365 set up correctly *and* the users' MS accounts are all licensed, then PCs should be able to connect to your AD using the public azureAD and allow people's "work accounts" to log in. The back end of that system can be pretty complicated though if it's not already setup (it's basically an AD-auth-only vpn), and wouldn't work for random personal accounts if you need that. School systems do this all the time.